Connect the ZKTTECO SDK with ASP.NET Core
I want to connect the ZKTTECO SDK with ASP.NET Core. I did not find any sources or information about
I tried to connect the sdk with asp core and it did not work. Has anyone tried this idea before and worked on it? Please help me Thanks

I also check the SDK list, I found the SDK last update is 2022, I suggest you could contact their support to see if there is the newest SDK with core.
